# Rounding a bitmap image as a google maps marker icon

Tags: java, android, google-maps, parsing, bitmap

I have a **map activity** that retrieves images and locations from a parse server
and show them as a marker on the map, I was wondering if I can make these markers rounded instead of the rectangle shape.

[image: it looks like this now]

Here is my code:

```
public void getimagesLocation(){

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Image");
    ParseGeoPoint geoPointLocation = new ParseGeoPoint();
    query.whereNear("location", geoPointLocation);

    query.setLimit(100);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.i("imageslocation", "no errors");}
            if (objects.size() > 0) {
                for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                    final ParseGeoPoint point = object.getParseGeoPoint("location");
                    ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.get("image");
                    file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null && data != null);

                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                            Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap,200,200);

                            Double lat = point.getLatitude();
                            Double log = point.getLongitude();

                            LatLng marker = new LatLng(lat, log);

                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .title("Another Image")
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(thumbnail))
                                    .position(marker));

                        }});}}}});}
```

So, how make these markers rounded instead of the rectangle shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alright i found a solution and here it is if someone is interested

```
 public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

then simply extracted the thumbnail using it like this

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(getCroppedBitmap(bitmap),200,200);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the image assets. You should use a **transparent *.png image format**.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: i dont think its related to the image format the images are taken by phone camera i just want a way to display them inside of a circle so they look rounded